# The name of this computation

Tags: calculus

For example, I have

$a + a² = 10 + a - b$

The compute result:

$a = \sqrt{10-b}$

Given the variable "a" in this example,  I want to extract it and put it at the left of the equation (the only thing at the left of the equal sign) and the equation is still correct.

What's the name of this kind of compute?

Thanks
Miles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply solving the equation $a + a^2 = 10 + a - b$ for $a$.

Comment: I really am.But is there a name? for example: 2/4 ==> 1/2 is Factorization. I want a name in analogy to the "Factorization" for my solving. Thanks

Comment: That is called "reducing a fraction "  not "factorization". As to the original question, there is not really an analogy, it is simply  "equation solving"